# Trouble getting distinct results in join query in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, distinct

I have two tables as following:

```
Mail_Thread
-------------
id,
thread_name,
created
```

,

```
Mail
----
id,
thread_id (FK for Mail_thread),
to,
subject,
message,
created
```

Here one thread contains multiple mails. So I want results to be of distinct thread and last message of that thread using join. So any possibilities ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You accomplish this with a series of joins in MySQL.  The first join connects threads to mail messages, and the second join restricts those mail messages to only the most recent ones for each thread.

```
SELECT t1.thread_name,
       t2.message
FROM Mail_Thread t1
INNER JOIN Mail t2
    ON t1.id = t2.thread_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT thread_id, MAX(created) AS max_created     -- this subquery identifies
    FROM Mail                                         -- the most recent message
    GROUP BY thread_id                                -- for each thread
) t3
    ON t2.thread_id = t3.thread_id AND
       t2.created   = t3.max_created
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select mt.id,mt.thread_name,mt.created
from mail_thread mt 
inner join mail m on mt.id =m.thread_id 
group by m.thread_id
order by mt.created desc
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.